# Custom Formula is making me crazy for making Case Comments Default to Public

Tags: workflow, internal-comments

Ok, I am trying to hack the Comments default to Public workflow.
I have made the Internal Comments field a part of my Cases but don't want them to be public. So this is the Formula that I came up with:

```
AND(
CreatedDate=NOW(),
ISPICKVAL(Parent.Division__c, "Therapy"),
Parent.LastModifiedDate<>CreatedDate
)
```

Then the normal Field update of Published to true.

The problem is this will work no problem when it's an IF instead of an AND. But when I change it to an AND it doesn't make anything public.
Any help would be amazing. Thanks!

BTW I tried to do this in Process Builder and I felt less confident so I went back to Workflow Rules.

Comment: What was you IF that worked? Also, instead of createdDate=NOW() use ISNEW()

Comment: Not sure whether I understand correctly. But is your new formula something like: IF(And(..., ..., ...), public, ...)? It should be a combination of IF and AND

Comment: Sorry, when it worked this was the formula: 
IF(
CreatedDate=NOW(),
ISPICKVAL(Parent.Division__c, "Therapy"),
Parent.LastModifiedDate<>CreatedDate
)

Comment: Alright, Eric, i changed the createdDate=NOW() to ISNEW() and made the workflow run anytime its created and edited and it works. It now makes comments from the Case Comment Related List Published, but the Internal Comments field stay unpublished. That's perfect. Thanks! I will remember to check different Functions! THANKS!